# Incorrect display of cell styles apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

First, I create a style in which I describe the location of the text

```
        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeight((short) (12 * 20));
        font.setFontName("Times New Roman");
         
        XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setWrapText(true);
        style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
        style.setFont(font);
```

Next, I create a basic style that I will apply to all cells.

```
XSSFCellStyle baseStyle = getBaseStyle(style, workbook);
....
public static XSSFCellStyle getBaseStyle(CellStyle style, XSSFWorkbook wb) {
    XSSFCellStyle baseStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    baseStyle.cloneStyleFrom(style);
    baseStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
    baseStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
    baseStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
    baseStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
    
    return baseStyle;
}
```

The problem is that the final style(baseStyle) I created is not displayed correctly in Excel
[image]

Desired result
[image]

Am I not using styles correctly? Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you calling `getBaseStyle` a lot? - if so, you will create a lot of style entries and excel limits the max number of styles and may ignore or just act up if the xlsx file has too many style entries

Comment: hello, i call it once, then I apply this style in a loop